# Loading .npy File Loads an Empty Array

Tags: arrays, numpy, save, load

I have a TfIDF matrix of size

```
tr_tfidf_q1.shape, tr_tfidf_q2.shape which gives 
( (404288, 83766), (404288, 83766) )
```

Now I save it using

```
np.save('tr_tfidf_q1.npy', tr_tfidf_q1)
```

When I load the file like this

```
f = np.load('tr_tfidf_q1.npy') 
f.shape() ## returns an empty array.
()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the size of the file (from OS)?

Comment: Its around 37MB. But i can it now as an array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [172]: from scipy import sparse
In [173]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(np.eye(10))
In [174]: np.save('test.npy',M)


In [175]: f=np.load('test.npy')
In [176]: f
Out[176]: 
array(<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

Note the `dtype=object` wrapper.  This has shape `()`, 0d.  A sparse matrix is not a regular array, or subclass.  So `np.save` resorts to wrapping it in an object array, and letting the object's own `pickle` method take care of the writing.

```
In [177]: f.item()
Out[177]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [178]: f.shape
Out[178]: ()
```

Using pickle directly:

```
In [181]: with open('test.pkl','wb') as f:
     ...:     pickle.dump(M,f)

In [182]: with open('test.pkl','rb') as f:
     ...:     M1=pickle.load(f)    
In [183]: M1
Out[183]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

The newest `scipy` release has new function for saving sparse matrices

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.save_npz.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

```
f = np.load('tr_tfidf.npy')
f ## returns the below.

array(<404288x83766 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 2117757 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, dtype=object)
```

I belive XYZ.shape works with references as well.

Comment: A `csr_matrix` is not a regular array, and is not saved directly by `np.save`.  Instead it wraps it in a 0d object array, and the sparse matrix is `pickled`.  So  `f.shape` is the shape of that wrapper.  `f.item()` should give you the sparse matrix itself.